# Three.js - Geometry vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm facing a problem after using THREE.GeometeryUtils.center(geometry) function,
Succesfully i center the mesh to screen center position using this function, my problem is, i need to get back the original vertices value that presented in geometry before centering. Please give your valuable suggestion

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code might help. It just might.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

- Compute the center of your geometry.
- Save this center in a vector3.
- Center your geometry in the scene.
- Apply a translation toward saved vector3 to restore its original position

Answer (score 0):

How about cloning the vertices before the merge operation ?

```
var oldVerts = [].concat(geometry.vertices);
THREE.GeometeryUtils.center(geometry);
```